# Android 3.1 soft keyboard in fullscreen mode

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm developing an application for Android 3.1. 
Is there a way to show (or forcing) the Android keyboard in fullscreen mode?

Comment: Just a quick clarification: Solutions mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard do not work in 3.1?

Comment: im think this maybr help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336762/disabling-the-fullscreen-editing-view-for-soft-keyboard-input-in-landscape

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171236/force-dialog-input-to-require-fullscreen-ime-soft-keyboard-in-landscape

Comment: i have the same problem in my surface view :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914290/android-soft-keyboard-in-a-fullscreen-surface-view

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

To hide, or:

```
activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

or:

```
activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

One of these should help you :)

Answer (score -1):

here comes two util functions, hope it helps

```
public static void showSoftKeyboard (Context context, View view) {
        try {
            ((InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
            .showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.w(TAG, "showSoftKeyboard->"+ex.toString());
        }
    }
    public static void hideSoftKeyboard (Context context, View view) {
        try {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.w(TAG, "hideSoftKeyboard->"+ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

...
*Social Coding @ [AspiroTV](https://github.com/AspiroTV)*