# How to force to remove keyboard after shown with SHOW_FORCED

Tags: android

I show keyboard with code

```
        ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                .toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
        etContent.requestFocus();
```

In next step I inflate new  LinearLayout and call setContentView(newLayout) and keyboard is still there. How to force to remove keyboard ? I tried with

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

but it didn't help. Can somebody suggest me solution ?

Comment: check this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647008/android-3-1-soft-keyboard-in-fullscreen-mode/7832810#7832810

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this out. I've used this to hide the soft input a number of times.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getContentView().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: +1 from me, thank you. If you happen to see this comment: do you know why the `setSoftInputMode()` alone sometimes does the trick and sometimes not?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, I imagine there are defaults for the method if you don't pass any arguments.

Comment: This is very helpful answer but `getContentView()` is not resolve in my Activity so, I just replace this by `getWindow().getDecorView()` . Now it is working perfectly for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should work

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getContentView().getWindowToken(), 0);
```