# How to hide Keyboard when starting activity on Galaxy tab?

Tags: android, keyboard, hide

I am using galaxy tab with Android 3.1, I am trying to start activity with EditText inside its layout file, but the problem is that each time I enter the activity the keyboard is automatically shown. I don't want the keyboard to be shown except when I click the EditText.

I used many solutions, all of them worked for many android devices except my **Galaxy Tab**.

Comment: it would be better if you even post what all you tried

Comment: Actually u were right coz I used the two answers below but also didn't work for Galaxy Tab

Answer (score 3):

Set the following to your activity inside **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Or in **onCreate** of your activity's code:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

---

Or try adding the following to your **onResume()**

```
try {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
catch (Exception e) { /* do nothing */ }
```

For more info, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7832810/966550)

Comment: is it a problem only with a specific model of galaxy tab? did you try any other tablet?

Comment: Yes it is as I mentioned above, actually I didn't use another tablet, also the edited answer by you has been used, thank you for your prompt response but unfortunately I don't know what is the problem

Comment: then it seems to be a problem with that specific version of ROM in your tab